# Making navigation available to all components in React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using `React Navigation 5` in my `React Native` app and I'm not exactly clear about how to make navigation available to all components. I also want to mention that my app uses `Redux` for state management but I didn't integrate `React Navigation` with `Redux` -- maybe I should!

My `App.js` renders my `Navigator.js` component which looks like below. BTW, my app requires authentication and one of the key functions of the navigator function is to redirect unauthenticated users to login screen.

```
class Navigator extends Component {

   render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                {
                   this.props.isAuthenticated
                   ? <MainMenuDrawer.Navigator drawerContent={(navigation) => <DrawerContent member={this.props.member} navigation={navigation} drawerActions={DrawerActions} handleClickLogOut={this.handleClickLogOut} />}>
                       <MainMenuDrawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
                       <MainMenuDrawer.Screen name="ToDoList" component={ToDoListStack} />
                     </MainMenuDrawer.Navigator>
                   : <SignInStack />
                }
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
      }
}
```

Then in my `HomeStack`, I have my `Dashboard` component which happens to be a class component that needs to access `navigation`. Here's my `HomeStack`:

```
const HomeStackNav = new createStackNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => {

   return(
      <HomeStackNav.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
         <HomeStackNav.Screen name="DashboardScreen" component={Dashboard} />
         <HomeStackNav.Screen name="SomeOtherScreen" component={SomeOtherComponent} />
      </HomeStackNav.Navigator>
   );
}

export default HomeStack;
```

Say, my `Dashboard` component looks like below. How do I make `navigation` available to this component?

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

   handleNav() {

      // Need to use navigation here...
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <Text>Welcome to Dashboard</Text>
         <Button onPress={() => this.handleNav()}>Go somewhere</Button>
      );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        member: state.app.member
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(appActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Do I need to pass `navigation` manually to each component? That seems too repetitive and prone to error. How do I make `navigation` available throughout my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1:

you can use [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility/) hook for functional component

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';


const navigation = useNavigation();

navigation.navigate("interests");
//or
navigation.push("interests");
```

## Solution 2:

you can use **HOC** `withNavigation` to navigation in props in any component for class component [Ref](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility/)

you can install `@react-navigation/compat` by

```
yarn add @react-navigation/compat
```

You can import like below

```
import { withNavigation } from '@react-navigation/compat';
```

you can use `withNavigation` like below

```
export default withNavigation(Dashboard)
```

**Note:** then you can use `this.props.navigation` in Dashboard component

Comment: Thank you for your response but isn't this a workaround? Doesn't the fact that `withNavigation` is part of the `@react-navigation/compat` package indicate we're not using the v5 API? Again, I appreciate your response. I just want to make sure I'm handling this right by v5 API standards.

Comment: yeah, you are using the right way. I just gave answer if you are unable to get navigation prop then you can get in any component like this

Comment: You're right. Looks like we either use `withNavigation` that comes with the `@react-navigation/compat` package OR as per documentation, wrap a class component inside a functional one which seems strange, just to access the `navigation` object. `withNavigation` seems like a cleaner approach. Here's the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Comment: @Sam `useNavigation` is a hook which can be use only in functional component not in class base component

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why the documentation suggests we wrap a class component inside a functional one -- see the link to docs -- which doesn't seem like a clean approach. That's why I said, `withNavigation` seems like a better solution.